# MySQL, Asterisk Dialplans and call forwarding

Tags: mysql, asterisk, telephony

How do I get Asterisk to forward incoming calls based on matching the incoming call number with a number to forward to? Both numbers are stored in a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I was looking for ended up looking like this:

```
[default]
exten => _X.,1,Set(ARRAY(${EXTEN}_phone)=${DTC_ICF(phone_number,${EXTEN})})
exten => _X.,n(callphone),Dial(SIP/metaswitch/${${EXTEN}_phone},26)
exten => _X.,n(end),Hangup()
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the long code sample, but more than half of it is debugging code to help you get it set up.

I'm assuming your server already has a modern version of PHP (at `/usr/bin/php`) with the PDO library, and that you have a database table named `fwd_table` with columns `caller_id` and `destination`.

In /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin get a copy of the [PHP AGI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpagi/) library. Then create a file named something like `forward_by_callerid.agi` that contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','false'); //Supress errors getting sent to the Asterisk process

require('phpagi.php');
$agi = new AGI();

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_hostname.';dbname='.$db_database.';charset=UTF-8', $db_user, $db_pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $agi->conlog("FAIL: Error connecting to the database! " . $e->getMessage());
    die();
}

$find_fwd_by_callerid = $pdo->prepare('SELECT destination FROM fwd_table WHERE caller_id=? ');

$caller_id = $agi->request['agi_callerid'];

if($callerid=="unknown" or $callerid=="private" or $callerid==""){
    $agi->conlog("Call came in without caller id, I give up");
    exit;
}else{
    $agi->conlog("Call came in with caller id number $caller_id.");
}

if($find_fwd_by_callerid->execute(array($caller_id)) === false){
    $agi->conlog("Database problem searching for forward destination (find_fwd_by_callerid), croaking");
    exit;
} 
$found_fwds = $find_fwd_by_callerid->fetchAll();
if(count($found_fwds) > 0){
    $destination = $found_contacts[0]['destination'];
    $agi->set_variable('FWD_TO', $destination);

    $agi->conlog("Caller ID matched, setting FWD_TO variable to ''");
}

?>
```

Then from the dial plan you can call it like this:

```
AGI(forward_by_callerid.agi)
```

And if your database has a match, it will set the variable `FWD_TO` with goodness.  Please edit your question if you need more help getting this integrated into your dial plan.